# ThreeJS "Removes" SVG Filter

Tags: javascript, css, three.js, svg-filters

I'm experiencing an issue with ThreeJS removing an SVG Filter after being loaded in. I'm struggling to pinpoint the issue, even a directional answer to look into what could be the cause would be greatly appreciated.

Desired Output before Cube is Rendered:
[image: BEFORE RENDER]

After Cube Is Rendered In:
[image: AFTER RENDER]

Javascript:

```
    const container = document.getElementById("container");
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );


    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
    renderer.setSize( container.clientWidth  , container.clientHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 );
    const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( );
    const ham = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { color: '#FF9D8E' } );
    const lettuce = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { color: '#ABE680' } );
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );

    camera.position.z = 5;
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };
    animate();
```

CSS:

```
:root {
   background:radial-gradient(#0d2f52 0%,black 40%) 20vw 10vh no-repeat black;
   filter:url('#noise') contrast(110%) !important;
  }
```

SVG :

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <!-- NOISE FILTER -->
        <filter id="noise" x="0vw" y="0vh" width="100vw" height="100vh">
            <feFlood flood-color="#808080" result="neutral-gray" />      
            <feTurbulence in="neutral-gray" type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.8" numOctaves="10" stitchTiles="stitch" result="noise"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="noise" type="saturate" values="0" result="destaturatedNoise"></feColorMatrix>
            <feComponentTransfer in="desaturatedNoise" result="theNoise">
                <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0 0.2 0"></feFuncA>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="theNoise" mode="soft-light" result="noisy-image"/>      
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Thanks for taking the time to go through my question!

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the "container.appendChild" command creating the issue. Continuing investigation.

Comment: Opted for a quick fix and created an element with the effect, then displayed it over the whole page as a background. Not satisfied, but reality hardly ever is.

Comment: The question can be closed as soon as possible! Thanks everyone :)